# Hot Code Reload does not work when building React Native app for physical iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, metro-bundler

As mentioned in the title, HCR doesn't work when I build an app for an iOS physical device that's plugged in via USB-C. However, it does work for Android physical devices or for iOS/Android simulators. The issue seems to be that the Metro Bundler doesn't connect to the device. I made sure that the device is connected to the same Wi-Fi network as the MacBook from where I run the build command.

The project uses **RN 0.69.9** (which I am aware that includes the fix for React-Codegen Pod), and I have **Xcode 14.3 (14E222b)** installed on the machine. HCR was working fine until the recent update to **Xcode 14.3 (14E222b)** along with the new Xcode Command Line Tools. Unfortunately, I cannot roll back to a previous version of Xcode, and I have to stick with this one. I am using **ios-deploy v1.12.1** (installed via brew), and I have also updated **frameworks.sh** to use `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`.

What I noticed is that when I build the app for an iOS physical device, I get the following warnings within Terminal (after executing `react-native run-ios --device` and finishing the build, they appear right before installing the app on the device):

```
xcodebuild[10046:322251] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
xcodebuild[10046:322374] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.InterfaceBuilderBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition
```

The Metro Bundler does not reload the app when pressing 'R', nor does it reload the app when I apply changes within the project.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried different Podfile changes (e.g. changing **SWIFT_VERSION** to **5.0**), but they did not help at all. Also, checked the **IP:PORT** to be sure things are fine.

Answer (score 0):

first of all make sure you have done the setup of react native environment on your machine, go to this [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native&platform=ios&os=macos) and follow all the steps to setup RN environment.

second:: have you added development team into your xcode > target > signing & Capabilities.
NOTE: if you did not added or have any development team in your xcode you cant run your app into physical device.

then, if environment setup is completed, do the following things

1. open `your_project.xcworkspace` file in xcode
2. clean build using `Command + Shift + K`
3. clear derived data ( press `Command + ,` then go to location tab then click arrow icon on path of derived data and delete it)
4. now connect your device to your system and allow the system if pops up
5. find your device name in simulator and device list and select it
6. now run your build using `Command + R`

make sure you reinstalled the pods before these steps

Comment: Already tried this and did not help. I've defined a script within `package.json` which I can run to remove **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData**, **~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods**, **/build**, **Pods**, and **Podfile.lock**; and then it runs  `pod setup`, and `pod install --repo-update`. I made sure that everything is cleared and fresh before build. The Development Team is properly defined and loaded within Xcode. As for the iOS device, made sure that it connects properly (I can see the device within MacOS and Xcode as destination target).

Comment: Everything was working fine until the recent update on Xcode (**Xcode 14.3** broke this bridge between iOS device and Metro Bundler). Unfortunately, I cannot roll back to the previous Xcode version due to some company rules.